# parsing xml using DOM parser and adding restrictions

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

I am trying to use DOM parser for my xml.The code is as follows. It lists all the elements by tag type and its properties like price and color. However its hard time for me to find out how to add restrictions to the code such as "give me all the pens that are above $10" or "the name of pen whose color is black". Can someone help me out.

Thanks
My .xml file looks something like this:

```
 <equipment>
  <type>
   <description>pen</description>
   <name>parker</name>
   <price value="USD">8.00</price>
   <color>black</color>
 </type>
  <type>
   <description>pen</description>
   <name>ball point</name>
   <price value="USD">20.00</price>
   <color>purple</color>
 </type>
 <type>
   <description>pen</description>
   <name>sharpie</name>
   <price value="USD">15.00</price>
   <color>blue</color>
 </type>
 <type>
   <description>pen</description>
   <name>staples</name>
   <price value="USD">6.00</price>
   <color>red</color>
 </type>
 <type>
   <description>pen</description>
   <name>integra</name>
   <price value="USD">12.00</price>
   <color>white</color>
 </type>
```

Here is the code for my parser

```
 public static void main(String[] args)throws SAXException, IOException,   ParserConfigurationException {

            File fXmlFile = new File("docs\\abc.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("type");
            for(int i=0;i<nList.getLength();i++){
                Node nNode = nList.item(i);

                    if(nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){

                        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                        System.out.println("Name:" + getTagValue("name", eElement));
                        System.out.println("Price: "+ getTagValue("price", eElement));
                        System.out.println(getAttributeValue("price", "value", eElement));
                        System.out.println("Description: "+getTagValue("description", eElement));
                        System.out.println("color:"+ getTagValue("color", eElement));
                    }
            }

        }

         private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
            NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();
            Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

            return nValue.getNodeValue();
         }

         private static String getAttributeValue(String sTag, String attributeName, Element eElement){
            NamedNodeMap nodeMap = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getAttributes();

            return nodeMap.getNamedItem(attributeName).getNodeValue();
         }
    }
```

Comment: Add your xml file here to solve your problem , it would be helpful for us ,

Comment: Hi, please find the above updated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to [parse XML based on some criteria](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html), you can use the [Java XPath API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html) instead of DOM based parser.

Comment: yupp tried xpath and it worked great!!!!! but want to try with programming though.

Comment: when you say "programming", you mean to retrieve the matched nodes and traverse through them in your code? If so, did you get a chance to check the first hyperlink in my response? It points a good tutorial from developer.ibm.com that compares DOM and XPath way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to add filters you better do it manually and using XMLStreamReader might help.follow the steps:

1. Transform your XML file into a string using Transformer
2. convert the String into a byte array and pass it to the XMLStreamReader.
3. Iterate from one element to another

---

```
Transformer t=TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
StringWriter sw=new StringWriter();         
StreamResult result=new StreamResult(sw);
DOMSource d=new DOMSource(XMLdoc);
t.transform(d, result);
tring xmlstring=sw.toString();

ByteArrayInputStream bain = new yteArrayInputStream(xmlstring.getBytes());
XMLInputFactory factory1 = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader reader = factory1.createXMLStreamReader(bain);

while(reader.hasNext())
{
    reader.next();
    if(reader.getEventType==XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT)
    {
        if(reader.getLocalName().equals("price"))
        {
            //your logic
        }
    }
}
```

hope it helps..